# Is this a Git bug?

Tags: git

I'm testing out the Git sparse checkout functionality, using the manual and [this page](http://jasonkarns.com/blog/subdirectory-checkouts-with-git-sparse-checkout/) as a guide. I tried checking out a directory by creating a sparse-checkout file with following contents (actual names hidden of course):

```
dir1/
```

Then I run `git read-tree -mu` and afterwards I see `dir1` in my repository as expected. Next I decide to checkout a new directory so I update the contents of the sparse-checkout file again to look like this:

```
dir1/
dir2/
```

Then I run `git read-tree -mu` and afterwards I see the following non-nested directories:

```
dir1
dir2
dir3
dir4
```

Why are the extra directories appearing? Is it a bug in Git? Note that if I remove `dir2/` from the sparse-checkout file they all seem to disappear as a group as well.

Comment: This isn't the behavior that is expected, but it's hard to debug without more information. This isn't that obscure a feature, so I really doubt it's a git bug. What happens if you list just "dir1/" and "dir3/" in your sparse-checkout file?

Comment: Then I just see dir1 and dir3 as expected.

Comment: I have a 14GB repository by the way. I don't know if it matters but it's really big.

Comment: Hmm...I wonder if it has to do with the specifics of the real name of "dir2"?

Comment: dir2 looks like "someWord" and dir3 looks like "anotherWord"

Comment: due to missing slash at start of dir: "dir2" should have read "/dir2"

Comment: balor123, you should write that as an answer and self-accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

due to missing slash at start of dir: "dir2" should have read "/dir2"